# "find_by" error while following Michel Hartl's tutorial, even with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I'm on the part where i must code to change the header links, depending on if the user is signed in or out.

When i add the code to the _header partial, even copied from the tutorial itself, when i reload the home page i get that red error page instead. It shows the message below:

```
undefined method `find_by' for #<#<Class:0x5b76358>:0x5b75b60>
```

And then it highlights the code

```
<% if signed_in? %>
```

Which is part of the code added to the _header partial.

So far, i coded exactly the code showed on the tutorial. I'm using Rails 4 by the way... so that 'find_by' method issue that we get from using older Rails versions it's not the case here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give a link to that part?

Comment: yep...  here it goes: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-changing_the_layout_links

Comment: maybe check your current_user method, just a guess

Comment: @Gracko what version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I'am using Rails 4 man. I said it in the question : )

Answer (score 0):

See learning from a material is good but i would recommend you not to copy the entire thing because it greatly reduces the amount of learning. Said that find_by is no direct method for models in rails for all versions if you want to find by `id` you can just use `find(id_value)` and if you want to find based on a particular column then you should use `find_by_columnname(column_value)` that will work. If you need more clarification or the error persists then pls ask.

Comment: False. There is `find_by` method in Rails 4.
http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Use Rails 4 instead of Rails 3.2 (which I think you use now) - `find_by` method was introduced in Rails 4 and Michael Hartl's tutorial is written for Rails 4.
2. Use dynamic finder where `find_by` method was used, for example:

   ```
   @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token)
   ```

Personally I would suggest solution 1.

Comment: Thank you. and I'AM using Rails 4 man. I said it in the question : )

Comment: By the way... solution 2 WORKED! Why this problem happened in the first place, since i'm using rails 4? What's up with the current_user method?